# Не срабатывает замена текста в функции preg_replace с кириллицей

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Версия php 5.3

Есть текст, получаемый с бд. Есть слова, получаемые также с бд. 
Необходимо заменить слова на *** в тексте совпадающие со словами не учитываю регистр. Если регистр учитывать, все получается. str_ireplace данная функция так же не срабатывает. Разбираясь я понял что дело в кириллице и в кодировке UTF-8. 
Хочу подметить, если чекать какая кодировка в каждой из переменных,  то везде UTF-8 кроме $str_replace, там ASCII. Функция mb_eregi_replace так же не срабатывает.

Если текст и слова писать в самом коде, не получая его с бд, то все проходит как необходимо без учета регистра.

```
$msg = preg_replace("/($key)/iu", $str_replace, $msg);
// $key - слово, которое необходимо заменить
// $str_replace - *** (звездочки)
// $msg - Текст

$msg = preg_replace("/(сделаю)/iu", '***', "я Сделаю"); // Этот вариант рабочий.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = preg_replace($key, $str_replace, $msg);
```

Comment: $msg = preg_replace($key, $str_replace, $msg); таким образом вообще NULL